# class PHPUnit\Framework\ExpectationFailedException not found

Tags: phpunit, zend-framework3, zend-test

when I try to run a failed test with this command :
`./vendor/bin/phpunit`
I get this Fatal Error :

```
PHPUnit 5.7.20 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\ExpectationFailedException' 
not found in /var/www/zend/vendor/zendframework/zend-
test/src/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php on line 444
```

Comment: have you tried to remove the vendor folder and start over again? Not as root (!): `$ rm -rf ./vendor && composer install`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "fixed" by a script in Zend\Test called `phpunit-class-aliases.php` but it's not configured properly IMHO since it's in the `autoload-dev` section (meaning it doesn't propagate out to other projects.)

So, in your project composer.json, do something like this:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "files": [
        "vendor/zendframework/zend-test/autoload/phpunit-class-aliases.php"
    ]
},
```

Then `composer install`

N.B. `Zend\Test` has a pull request that fixes this very thing, but they're saying it's PHPUnit's fault (Shame on you PHPUnit 4 for... idunno... having the wrong class name according to Zend\Test)  So, I've done it instead: `composer require illchuk/phpunit-class-aliases`

Answer (score 4):

Your version of phpunit is probably too old for your version of Zend. The class `PHPUnit\Framework\ExpectationFailedException` have been renamed in PhpUnit 6.X from `PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException` to `ExpectationFailedException`

Please check your PhpUnit version: `phpunit --version`, it should be 6.X. Update it to the last version to avoid this error.

Comment: the problem is that phpunit 6.X is not working with php 5.X

Answer (score 3):

This is a configuration flaw in zend-test. It consumes classes from Phpunit 6 but per it's Composer requirements, [Phpunit before that version are OK to  require](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-test/blob/master/composer.json#L25):

```
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.0 || ^5.0 || ^6.0",
```

Most likely as your system because of the PHP version does not satisfy the requirements of Phpunit 6, the next lower version was installed.

As the code in the base test case (https://github.com/zendframework/zend-test/blob/master/src/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php#L444) makes use of Phpunit 6 classes, I strongly assume that when the configuration flaw is made aware to the Zend-Test project, you won't be even able to install on your system any longer.

Therefore upgrade to a recent PHP version and then run

```
composer update
```

If you're stuk with the PHP version, downgrade zend-test to a version that supports an older Phpunit version. I don't know that project well, so it's just a suggestion, I don't know if such a version exists or can't even recommend one.

I filed a report, perhaps using that one class was an oversight or there is a less hard way to resolve the dependency: https://github.com/zendframework/zend-test/issues/50